# Combine Unity games in one app

Tags: unity

I want to combine multiple Unity games in one Unity app (or other framework if necessary). This app would have a bunch of buttons that will start the desired game. Is this possible and what would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Simply no.  If you need to do something like this, you will need to use scenes.

Comment: It is absolutely doable. I have worked on such an application before. However, consider if it is really worth it, because I hated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene handling system of Unity makes each scene essentially a separate game.

So you can easily do this by importing all assets and all scenes of the games into one Unity project and then add a launcher scene which allows the player to choose the game. On click of the appropriate button the start-scene of that game is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would you handle the namespaces of the various projects? Wouldn't they interfere with each other?

Comment: @Jenthe Yes, they would interfere with each other. When you have two different assets in two different games with the same name you would have to rename one of them manually.